# Olympiad Inequality which can be solved using Cauchy–Schwarz inequality

Tags: inequality, summation, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

$x,y,z$ are positive real numbers, such that $x+y+z=3$ . prove that :

$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{x}{x^3+y^2+z} \leq 1 $$

I tried many things , but I don't think any of those are worth of mentioning.
However, I know problem can be solves using Cauchy–Schwarz inequality.

Please, share your ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Since this is contest-math, please indicate a source for the problem.

Comment: There is an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1962291/upper-bound-on-displaystyle-sum-textcyc-dfracaa3b2c?noredirect=1) but it uses Holder's inequality. Read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363544/inequality-sum-cyc-fracaca3b2-leq-frac12?noredirect=1) as well. I think this is safely not a current contest question because of the similarities to the questions I've just presented.

Comment: Unfortunately , I don't know where the problem comes from. It was on IZHO TST in my city few years ago, but I don't think they came up with it.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome! If you are able to write an answer using only AM-GM and using the hints given, it will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{x^3+y^2+z}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{x\left(\frac{1}{x}+1+z\right)}{(x^3+y^2+z)\left(\frac{1}{x}+1+z\right)}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{(1+x+xz)}{(x+y+z)^2}\leq1.$$
Can you end it now?