# Approach to inequality proofs

Tags: inequality, contest-math, problem-solving

I have read much of the theory about inequalities but cannot solve sums from them of Maths Olympiad.  What should be my general approach to solve them. I can share a few sums.

> Let a, b, c be positive real numbers such that
> $\frac
> {a}{1+a}+\frac{b}{1+b}+\frac
> {c}{1+c}=1$.
> Prove that $abc ≤ 1/8$.

> $a,b,c$ are real number with $a+b+c=1$
> Prove that $\sum_{cyc}{\frac{a}{a²+b³+c³}}≤\frac{1}{5abc}$

I do not need solution to these sums as I have the solutions. But I am unable to solve inequality sums of this kind. What should be my strategy to solve these sums? Any suggestion will be extremely helpful.

Comment: If you have the solutions, as you say, then you also have a way to approach these questions. If you study $100$ of these questions, you have enough approaches and you can solve $99$ percent then. This site has at least $100$ such inequality questions with solutions. There are also books. Let me give one example - solve by Cauchy-Schwarz, e.g., like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4256556/olympiad-inequality-which-can-be-solved-using-cauchy-schwarz-inequality).

Comment: @DietrichBurde, the problem with me is that I fully understand the solutions once I see it after spending hours on the sum but when given another sum, I cannot solve it.

Comment: But one can practice that. If you do several inequalities by, say, Cauchy-Schwarz, you will finally be able to attack another one, which can be solved by it. There are of course more methods, so it takes time.

Comment: I also study for olympiad. For me inequality are the hardest part. however I can tell you that I trained to solve with AM-GM and Cauchy-Schwarz and I improved, even if I'm not very good yet...
However, I advise you to do many exercises, and not to read the solution before having worked on it for hours. From personal experience, doing many exercises even without success and then reading the solution only after hours of work, gives better results if reading many exercises done.

Comment: @StCS Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Sarban Bhattacharya You are welcome. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, I understand your problem: you say that you fully understand solutions, but you can't solve a new problem by yourself. It happens  because you don't try to solve a problem with a "fully understandable solution".

Just try to solve a problem, for which a solution you think that you understood, and write this solution!

For example. Take a problem from the Dietrich Burde's link:

> Let $x,$ $y$ and $z$ be positive numbers, such that $x+y+z=3$ . Prove that :

$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{x}{x^3+y^2+z} \leq 1.$$

1. Try to solve this problem by yourself without to see a solution, although you are convinced that you have seen the proof and understood it.
2. If you can't find a solution, so read a solution and go back to 1.
3. If you think that you know already a solution of the problem, so write a full solution.
4. If you can't  write a full solution, so go back to 1.

Try to repeat these things until the moment, that you succeed to write a full solution.

This is a first step. After this you can try to understand, how we can solve this problem by another way, how we can guess the solution,  how we can create a similar problem and more.

Do it with all problems and you'll start to solve problems by yourself. Good luck!